# how to returns the index of the smallest element in the list in python

Tags: python

In my code,  returns the position of the smallest element in the list by use index() function, when I run the code, it run nothing. Please help me to figure out problem. Here is what I coded:

```
def get_index_of_smallest(numbers):
    smallest_index = []
    for element in range (len(numbers)):
        element = numbers.index(min(numbers))
        smallest_index = element + 1
    return smallest_index

def test_get_index_of_smallest():
    list1 = [23, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9, 7, 4]
    print(get_index_of_smallest(list1))
```

Many thanks.

Comment: min(list1), done

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min(list)` and builtin function of `list`(`list.index()`)

```
list1 = [23, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9, 7, 4]
min_num = min(list1)
index = list1.index(min_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, it's possible using `min`, `emumerate` and `lambda`

```
myList = [23, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9, 7, 4]
min(enumerate(myList), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
#1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, but you forgot to call the function. Add `test_get_index_of_smallest()`, and it will work!

Input:

```
def get_index_of_smallest(numbers):
    smallest_index = []
    for element in range (len(numbers)):
        element = numbers.index(min(numbers))
        smallest_index = element + 1
    return smallest_index

def test_get_index_of_smallest():
    list1 = [23, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9, 7, 4]
    print(get_index_of_smallest(list1))

test_get_index_of_smallest()
```

Output:

```
2
```

---

Edit:
You can further cut down your code. Here is a code that does the same thing:

Input:

```
def get_index_of_smallest(numbers):
    return numbers.index(min(numbers))+1

print(get_index_of_smallest([23, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9, 7, 4]))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Do I have other solutions to let my code works, I feel my code still have some problems. Thanks

Comment: You code works just fine, however, I have added a shorter code that does the same thing as the code you posted. See my edit.

Comment: The correct output of what I want is "1", do I just delete the "+1" in my code?

Comment: @Christina yes, don't add 1 he must have assume that since you are doing +1 in your code you may want the index to be in that way.

Comment: Please consider marking this problem with the checkmark to the left of the question if you think it is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use list comprehension and enumerate here

```
min_idx = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(list1) if item == min(list1)]
```

> ```
> [1]
> ```

Here is a expanded version of what is going on here

```
for idx, item in enumerate(list1):
    if item == min(list1):
        min_idx = idx
```

When we `enumerate` in it iterates for the `index` and `item` so what we can do is check each `item` v `min(list1)` if we get a match we can set our `min_idx` variable to the corresponding `index` of that `item`, cheers !